# useState в React

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, create-react-app

Прошу мне объяснить.
У меня есть:

```js
const [dialogs, setDialogs] = useState([
  {
    chat_id: 0,
    messages: [
      {
        chat_id: 0,
        text: "test1"
      },
      {
        chat_id: 0,
        text: "test2"
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

Как мне вставить ещё один объект в массив messages, через setDialogs?

Comment: Напрямую никак. Вытащить значение dialogs, взять messages, запушить туда значение, а потом через setDialogs обновить состояние dialogs

Comment: А теперь тоже самое, только кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [dialogs, setDialogs] = useState([
  {
    chat_id: 0,
    messages: [
      {
        chat_id: 0,
        text: "test1"
      },
      {
        chat_id: 0,
        text: "test2"
      }
    ]
  }
]);

// ...

setDialogs(p => {
    const copy = [...p]; // shallow copy
    copy[0].messages.push(newMessage);
    return copy;
});
```